# Merge dev branch into master issue with git

Tags: git, codeigniter, merge

I'm still relatively new to version control and thought I was being clever with the following. I was updating a CodeIgniter site to version 3 from 2. I branched master to CI_UPGRADE_3, did the upgrade the merged back to master.

It broke. The system folders files had the old and new entries in the files. I managed to get back to "pre" merge and am now in my CI_UPGRADE_3 branch wondering how I get back to master with the version on CI_UPGRADE_3.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What probably happened is someone else commited things on master while you were working.

No other possibilies: merge master into your branch, fix the conflicts and integrate the other modifications.

Then, when all looks ok on your branch, merge it into master. It should be a fast forward, and thus **master will have exactly what you had on your branch.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. So was my mistake to merge the dev branch into master? Will the duplicate entries go if I do it the other way?

Comment: No, they will stay exactly the same way. It just gives you opportunity to fix them up before they are on master.

Comment: Ah I see, so after the merge, is there another command to run? Sorry I'm just not grasping this